# Define limits based on size type

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Ok I'm really quite stuck on this and it might be nice to throw around some ideas, this may be a long'ish post.

Firstly let me try and explain what I'm trying to do. Currently I have a model called Book with a nested model called Snippets. I have a column called size in my Book model which defines if it is [0 => 'Short', 1 => 'Medium', 2 => 'Long']. I've also got a total word count in my Book controller which will give me the amount of words in every snippet. Now what I want to try and do is depending on the size [0,1,2] define a different limit on the word count. Example shown below

Size (content length validation) |   Word Count

Short (500) per creation         |  20,000 words in total

Medium (700) per creation        |  50,000 words in total

Long (1000) per creation         | 100,000 words in total

**current_word_count - total_word_count depending on size [short,med,long]**

So depending on the size defined in Book which I have working now I would like the total amount of words for snippets in that book to be defined by model including all current posts so for example if I have a short book and I have 10,000 words already in snippets there should be 10,000 left. The reason I have thought it through this way was because not every user will always post the maximum required.

Now for the code.

First the models:

Book.rb

```
class Book < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :snippets
  attr_accessible :title, :book_id, :size


  def get_word_count
    @word_count = 0
    self.snippets.each.do |c|
    @word_count += c.content.scan(/\w+/).size
   end

  def short?
   size == 0
  end

  def medium?
    size == 1
  end

  def long?
    size == 2
  end
end
```

Snippet.rb

```
class Snippet < ActiveRecord::Base
  before_create :check_limit
  belongs_to :book
   attr_accessible :content, :book_id 

  validates :book_id, presence: true
  #validates_length_of :content, less_than: 200, if: book.small?
  #validates_length_of :content, less_than: 500, if: book.medium?
  #validates_length_of :content, less_than: 1000, if: book.long?


    def check_limit         
      if book.word_limit_reached?
        errors.add :base, 'Snippet limit reached.'           
        return false
      end       
      return true
    end 
end
```

Seeing as this is a database action I won't really need to touch the controller just yet until I have defined these rules. I've been sat here trying various things but as I'm still new to Rails I'm just trying to do this to get my head around the code and the things you can do.

As always I appreciate your help and feedback.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ahh, custom validation goodness, this is what I would do:

book.rb

```
class Book < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :snippets


  def get_word_count
    @word_count = []
    self.snippets.each do |c|
      @word_count << c.content.scan(/\w+/).size
    end
    @word_count = @word_count.inject(:+)
    # Similar to what you had before, but this creates an array, and adds each 
    # content size to the array, the inject(:+) is a method done on an array to sum 
    # each element of the array, doesn't work with older versions of ruby, but it's safe
    # 1.9.2 and up
  end

  def short?
    size == 0
  end

  def medium?
    size == 1
  end

  def long?
    size == 2
  end
end
```

Snippet.rb

```
class Snippet < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :book
  validate :size_limit

  # Here I created a constant containing a hash with your book limitation parameters
  # This way you can compare against it easily
  BOOK_SIZE = { 
    0 => {"per" => 500, "total" => 20000},
    1 => {"per" => 700, "total" => 50000},
    2 => {"per" => 1000, "total" => 100000}
  }   


  def  size_limit
    # Sets the book size, which is the same as the hash key for your constant BOOK_SIZE
    book_limit = self.book.size
    # Scans the content attribute and sets the word count
    word_count = self.content.scan(/\w+/).size
    # This is getting the total word count, for all the snippets and the new snippet
    # the user wants to save
    current_snippets_size = (self.book.get_word_count || 0) + word_count
    # This is where your validation magic happens.  There are 2 comparisons done and if they
    # don't both pass, add an error that can be passed back to the controller.  
    # 1st If your content attribute is smaller than allowed for that particular book
    # 2nd If your total snippets content for all previous and current snippet are less than
    # allowed by the total book size defined in the constant
    errors.add(:content, "Content size is too big") unless word_count < BOOK_SIZE[book_limit]['per'] && current_snippets_size < BOOK_SIZE[book_limit]['total']
  end 

end
```

Comment: Dude, you are a god! It's going to take me a while to understand this maybe you could walk me through what each line is doing so I can get to grips with this code, I understand most of it.